# Difference between JSFiddle and local JS files?

Tags: javascript, html

I get different outputs from running in JSFiddle vs. in my local environment. I only have 2 files: index.html and slider.js

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uyq29nsw/)

My local file setup:

```
asdf$ cat index.html
<html>
  <body>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>


asdf$ cat slider.js 
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

When I open the html file with Firefox and Chrome, however, I see the "demo" value is invisible. The width is the window width, and the height is 0. Why does this happen?

Comment: JSFiddle will embed your javascript for you, you need to reference the js file in your html. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Does it matter where I put that line? should it go in the beginning of the body or the div sections (& which one)?

Comment: inside the body tag (just before `</body>`, **after** the elements the code references

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you! It worked :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Your question is being downvoted because you may not have researched. Being new at this, you may not even know what to research though. I encourage you to try out a few tutorials and make sure to research your issue prior to posting a question, but feel free to post. Even if you get downvoted, you may learn something. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you commenters! This is what the index.html file should've looked like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div id="demo"></div>

    <script src="slider.js"></script> <!-- important!!!  -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It turns out that JSFiddle embeds the javascript files for us, but we have to do this ourselves while developing.

Result:
[image]